# react-codemirror2 hinting function

Tags: reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

```
editor.on('keyup',function(cm,event){
            if(!cm.state.completionActive && (event.keyCode||event.which) != 13 && (event.keyCode||event.which)>64 && (event.keyCode||event.which)<91 && !event.altKey && !event.ctrlKey &&!ExcludedIntelliSenseTriggerKeys[(event.keyCode || event.which).toString()] ){
                cm.showHint({hint:CodeMirror.hint.anyword, completeSingle: false, `alignWithWord:false});` 
            }
        })
```

throwing error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'anyword' of undefined

i have already imported the necessary addon files required for hinting but still getting error.

Comment: that is telling you that CodeMirror.hint is undefined, can you expand your question to tell us where you are getting that/setting it/etc...

Comment: that's what i am saying why hint is undefined when i have imported hint addon related files